# How do I resolve a single reference with Python jsonschema RefResolver

Tags: python, jsonschema

I am writing Python code to validate a .csv file using a JSON schema and the jsonschema Python module.  I have a clinical manifest schema that looks like this:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "$id": "http://example.com/veoibd_schema.json",
  "title": "clinical data manifest schema",
  "description": "Validates clinical data manifests",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "individualID": {
      "type": "string",
      "pattern": "^CENTER-"
    },
    "medicationAtDx": {
      "$ref": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/not-my-username/validation_schemas/reference_definitions/clinicalData.json#/definitions/medicationAtDx"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "individualID",
    "medicationAtDx"
  ]
}
```

The schema referenced by the $ref looks like this:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "$id": "http://example.com/clinicalData.json",
  "definitions":{
    "ageDxYears": {
      "description": "Age in years at diagnosis",
      "type": "number",
      "minimum": 0,
      "maximum": 90
    },
    "ageOnset": {
      "description": "Age in years of first symptoms",
      "type": "number",
      "exclusiveMinimum": 0
    },
    "medicationAtDx": {
      "description": "Medication prescribed at diagnosis",
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

(Note that both schemas are quite a bit larger and have been edited for brevity.)

I need to be able to figure out the "type" of "medicationAtDx" and am trying to figure out how to use jsonschema.RefResolver to de-reference it, but am a little lost in the terminology used in the documentation and can't find a good example that explains what the parameters are and what it returns "in small words", i.e. something that a beginning JSON schema user would easily understand.

I created a RefResolver from the clinical manifest schema:

```
import jsonschema


testref = jsonschema.RefResolver.from_schema(clin_manifest_schema)
```

I fed it the url in the "$ref":

```
meddx_url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/not-my-username/validation_schemas/reference_definitions/clinicalData.json#/definitions/medicationAtDx"

testref.resolve_remote(meddx_url)["definitions"].keys()
```

What I was expecting to get back was:

```
dict_keys(['medicationAtDx'])
```

What I actually got back was:

```
dict_keys(['ageDxYears', 'ageOnset', 'medicationAtDx'])
```

Is this the expected behavior?  If not, how can I narrow it down to just the definition for "medicationAtDx"?  I can traverse the whole dictionary to get what I want if I have to, but I'd rather have it return just the reference I need.

Thanks in advance!

ETA: per Relequestual's comment below, I took a couple of passes with resolve_fragment as follows:

```
ref_doc = meddx_url.split("#")[0]
ref_frag = meddx_url.split("#")[1]
testref.resolve_fragment(ref_doc, ref_frag)
```

This gives me "TypeError: string indices must be integers" and "RefResolutionError: Unresolvable JSON pointer".  I tried tweaking the parameters in different ways (adding the "#" back into the fragment, removing the leading slash, etc.) and got the same results.  Relequestual's explanation of a fragment was very helpful, but apparently I'm still not understanding the exact parameters that resolve_fragment is expecting.

Comment: I think you want to look at `resolve_fragment` in the docs. In your ref URI, anything after the hash # is a fragment. https://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.io/en/stable/references/#jsonschema.RefResolver.resolve_fragment Sorry I can't be much more help than that. Let me know if you can't make any progress.

Comment: For what it's worth, resolving JSON references is one of the most difficult aspects of working with multi-file JSON Schemas.